# Iterate between two arrays within a single loop

Tags: bash, loops, variables, declare

I have these variables:

```
bridge_xa_name_list=( "$br_int0_srxa" "$br_int1_srxa" "$br_int2_srxa" "$br_int6_srxa" "$br_int7_srxa" "$br_wan3_srxa1" "$br_wan3_srxa2" )
bridge_xb_name_list=( "$br_int0_srxb" "$br_int1_srxb" "$br_int2_srxb" "$br_int6_srxb" "$br_int7_srxb" "$br_wan3_srxb1" "$br_wan3_srxb2" )
```

I am trying to use a single loop to iterate all the elements for each array.

At the moment I have a functioning loop but only by referencing the $bridge_xa_name_list

```
   for a in "${bridge_xa_name_list[@]}"; do
        shell_echo_textval_green "Network Bridge Name Detected" "$a"

        sleep 1
        shell_echo_text "Verifying $a network State"
        virsh_net_list=$(virsh net-list | grep active | grep $a)    

        if [[ ! $virsh_net_list == *"active" ]]
        then
            shell_echo "[Inactive]"
        else
            shell_echo "[Active]"
            shell_echo_green "$a.xml found. Undefining anyway."
            virsh net-undefine $a
        fi
            
        shell_echo_text "File $a.xml is at $srxa_fld_path"
        if [[ -f ${srxa_fld_path}${a}.xml ]]
        then
            shell_echo "[Yes]"
        else
            shell_echo "[Not Found]"
            shell_echo_text "Attempting to copy $a.xml template to ~/config/$srxa_nm"
            cp $xml_file_path $srxa_fld_path${a}.xml
            shell_echo ["Copied"]

            #Check if Copy was sucessfull
                if [[ -f $srxa_fld_path${a}.xml ]]
                then    
                    :
                else
                    shell_echo_red "[Failed]"
                    shell_echo_red "There was an error when trying to copy ${a}.xml"
                    shell_echo_error_banner "Script Aborted! 1 error(s)"
                    exit 1              
                fi
done
```

**$a** in my script is iterating all the elements from the 1st array. However, I would like to include the second array as part of the same loop.

Comment: Your script starts with 2 equal lines `for a in "${bridge_xa_name_list[@]}"; do`. Remove one of them or change the second into `for b in "${bridge_xb_name_list[@]}"; do`.

Comment: Lol That was a typo. I copied the loop twice Sorry

Comment: When you say you want to use just one variable to access both arrays within the same loop, do you mean to access *corresponding elements* of the two arrays both in the same iteration?  Or would it be sufficient to simply loop over all the `xa`s followed by all the `xb`s?

Comment: Is that script really the briefest script you could come up with to demonstrate the problem you're asking for help with? I suspect it isn't - please create and post a [mcve] that just demonstrates the problem, don't just post whatever code you have lying around that contains the problem somewhere within it. See [ask].

Comment: a minimal example should consist of the the loop(s) and some `echo` calls to display the loop variables; all of the `shell_echo*`, `cp`, `virsh`, `if/then/else/fi` code is just noise and doesn't appear to have anything to do with the main objective of iterating between arrays

Comment: it's not clear (to me) what you mean by 'iterate between arrays; do you want to process all elements of the 1st array and then all of the elements of the 2nd array? do you need to process the 1st element of both arrays, then the 2nd element of both arrays, ... then the Nth element of both arrays (and if so, what to do if the arrays don't have the same number of elements)? on each pass through the loop do you need to process one element from one of the arrays based on a condition?

Comment: When you have array `(a,b)` and `(c,d)`, what do you want? Process `a, b, c, d`, or `(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)` or `(a,c),(b,d)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **$a** in my script is iterating all the elements from the 1st array. However, I would like to include the second array as part of the same loop.

I think you mean that you want to execute the loop body once for each element of `bridge_xa_name_list` and also once, separately, for each element of `bridge_xb_name_list`, without duplicating the body of the loop.  Yes, there are at least two easy ways to do that:

1. Absolutely easiest would be to just specify the additional elements in the loop header:

   ```
   for a in "${bridge_xa_name_list[@]}" "${bridge_xb_name_list[@]}"; do
     # loop body ...
   ```

   What you need to understand here is that the `for` loop syntax has nothing in particular to do with accessing an array.  The `in` list of such a command designates zero or more individual values (shell "words") to iterate over, which in the case of your original code are produced by a parameter expansion involving array-valued parameter `bridge_xa_name_list`.  But this is just a special case of the shell's general procedure of expanding each command (path expansion, parameter expansion, command expansion, *etc*.) before executing it.  You can use that however you like.

   **OR**
2. Make a function around the loop that executes it once for every function argument.  Then  call that function once for each array:

   ```
   my_loop() {
     for a in "$@"; do
       # loop body
     done
   }

   # ...

   my_loop "${bridge_xa_name_list[@]}"
   my_loop "${bridge_xb_name_list[@]}"
   ```

   Note that this still exhibits the same expand-then-execute behavior described in the previous item, which is why you have to pass *the expansion* of each array (to one word per element).  There is no direct way to pass the whole array as a single argument.

   Note also that the shell supports a special shortcut for iterating over all the elements of `$@`.  For that particular case, you can omit the `in` list altogether:

   ```
   my_loop() {
     for a; do
       # loop body
     done
   }
   ```

Of course, you can also combine the above, by providing the function and calling it once with the elements of both arrays:

```
my_loop "${bridge_xa_name_list[@]}" "${bridge_xb_name_list[@]}"
```

Answer (score 4):

These are indexed arrays so you can iterate over the indexes:

```sh
for (( i = 0; i < ${#bridge_xa_name_list[@]}; i++ )); do
  echo "${bridge_xa_name_list[i]}"
  echo "${bridge_xb_name_list[i]}"
done
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I would need to expand my script double to fit the other array? Is there a way to reference both arrays within one letter like $a? Sorry I'm not an expert in bash. I'll update the question a portion of the script so you know what I mean

Comment: You can change the lines with `echo` like `a="${bridge_xa_name_list[i]}"` and `b="${bridge_xb_name_list[i]}"`. This solution will only iterate over pairs `(a,b)` where they have the same index in the arrays. When you want all combinations of elements from both arrays, your question was unclear.